# grep regex whitespace behavior

Tags: regex, grep, gnu

I have a textfile, containing something like:

```
12,34 EUR 
 5,67 EUR
 ...
```

There is one whitespace before 'EUR' and I ignore 0,XX EUR.

I tried:

`grep '[1-9][0-9]*,[0-9]\{2\}\sEUR' => didn't match !`

`grep '[1-9][0-9]*,[0-9]\{2\} EUR' => worked !`

`grep '[1-9][0-9]*,[0-9]\{2\}\s*EUR' => worked !`

`grep '[1-9][0-9]*,[0-9]\{2\}\s[E]UR'  => worked !`

Can somebody explain me pls, why I can't use `\s` but `\s*` and `\s[E]` matched?

OS: Ubuntu 10.04, grep v2.5

Answer (score 155, accepted):

This looks like a behavior difference in the handling of `\s` between grep 2.5 and newer versions (a bug in old grep?).  I confirm your result with grep 2.5.4, but all four of your greps do work when using grep 2.6.3 (Ubuntu 10.10).

Note:

```
GNU grep 2.5.4
echo "foo bar" | grep "\s"
   (doesn't match)
```

whereas

```
GNU grep 2.6.3
echo "foo bar" | grep "\s"
foo bar
```

Probably less trouble (as `\s` is not documented):

```
Both GNU greps
echo "foo bar" | grep "[[:space:]]"
foo bar
```

My advice is to avoid using `\s` ... use `[ \t]*` or `[[:space:]]` or something like it instead.

Comment: Or just `[:space:]`, for ex. like this: `cat file | grep "[[:space:]]"`

Comment: it seems to be a bug in the newer version of grep (other point of view) according to this bug request http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-grep@gnu.org/msg02686.html but why does the last statement match?

Comment: @Milde, note the followup post http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-grep@gnu.org/msg02689.html where that bug report was marked invalid and closed (so this is not considered to be a bug in newer grep).

Comment: @Milde, none of the grep documentation I've examined (old or new) actually refers to `\s` at all.  I'd say its behavior is "undefined".  Use [:space:] instead, which works as documented in old and new grep.

Comment: thanks, I will use [:space:] in the future to avoid the problem

Comment: @BaiyanHuang \t doesn't seem to work on whatever version I'm using right now. I'm using it with color highlighting, and `echo 'a\sb ct' | grep '[ \t]'` highlights the \ and the t. It is whatever version comes bundled with the Windows git install that's on this computer.

Comment: With grep 2.20 I have to use the extended flag `-E`: `grep -E "\s"` and `grep -E "[[:space:]]"`

Comment: Note that on linux it is recommended to use single-quotes around your regex to avoid the shell handling backslash characters (taking them to escape special shell characters) instead of passing them through to grep/other command as part of the regex/parameter. e.g. `echo '\\'` will output both backslashes, but `echo "\\"` will output a single backslash (because the shell substitutes it). This does get a bit hairy if you need to include a single-quote character in your regex though. (You may need a combination of single-quoted bits and double-quoted bits etc.)