# grep with regexp: whitespace doesn't match unless I add an assertion

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

GNU grep 2.5.4 on bash 4.1.5(1) on Ubuntu 10.04

This matches

```
$ echo "this is a     line" | grep 'a[[:space:]]\+line'
this is a     line
```

But this doesn't

```
$ echo "this is a     line" | grep 'a\s\+line'
```

But this matches too

```
$ echo "this is a     line" | grep 'a\s\+\bline'
this is a     line
```

I don't understand why #2 does not match (whereas # 1 does) and #3 also shows a match. Whats the difference here?

Comment: it works for me with GNU grep 2.8 $ echo "this is a     line" | grep 'a\s\+line' ; echo $?
this is a     line
0

Comment: 2 and 3 don't work for me (GNU grep 2.5.1)

Comment: All three work for me: Cygwin with GNU grep 2.6.3

Comment: I am more interested in knowing why #2 does not match but #3 does. An extra zero width assertion (word boundary) makes such a difference ?

Comment: Because of bugs in grep 2.5

Look here: [Grep white space behavior][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233159/grep-regex-whitespace-behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at your `grep` manpage. Perl added a lot of regular expression extensions that weren't in the original specification. However, because they proved so useful, many programs adopted them.

Unfortunately, `grep` is sometimes stuck in the past because you want to make sure your `grep` command remains compatible with older versions of `grep`.

Some systems have `egrep` with some extensions. Others allow you to use `grep -E` to get them. Still others have a `grep -P` that allows you to use Perl extensions. I believe Linux systems' grep command can use the `-P` extension which is not available in most Unix systems unless someone has replaced the grep with the GNU version. Newer versions of Mac OS X also support the `-P` switch, but not older versions.

Comment: I am more interested in knowing why #2 does not match but #3 does. An extra zero width assertion (word boundary) makes such a difference ?

Comment: Actually, both work for #2 and #3 me. I did this on Cygwin and on the most recent release of Ubuntu Linux running on Virtual Box on my PC. I haven't tried it on my Mac at home. Neither work on our Solaris system since it doesn't use the GNU version of `grep` and doesn't recognize anything besides the very basic regex. Is there anything in that wide blank space besides spaces? A tab character perhaps?

Comment: I tried again. But there is no tab character there. This is kind of puzzling and surprising.

Answer (score 4):

`grep` doesn't support the complete set of regular expressions, so try using `-P` to enable perl regular expressions. You don't need to escape the `+` i.e.

```
echo "this is a     line" | grep -P 'a\s+line'
```

Comment: I am more interested in knowing why #2 does not match but #3 does. An extra zero width assertion (word boundary) makes such a difference ?