# Get lines that end with "$" in a text file

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have an output like this:

```
a/foo bar /
b/c/foo sth /xyz
cc/bar ghj /axz/byz
```

What i want is just this line:

```
a/foo bar /
```

To be more clear, I want those line ending with a specific string. I want to `grep` lines that have a `/` character at their last column.

Comment: What is your criteria for picking that line and not the others?

Comment: Edited the question. I want a line, ends with some special pattern

Comment: if the line is "a/foo bar bb/", do you want to show it?  your requirement  "I want to grep lines that has a "/" character at their last column" actually you have "/" character at last column of all three lines output you showed......may be your requirement can be corrected to more clear way? thanks

Comment: may be I misunderstood the definition of column.... Is all lines of your outputs 3 columns that delimited by whitespace?

Comment: maybe yes, maybe not. the important thing is, the line should end with "/" character.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `$` like this:

```
$ grep '/$' file
a/foo bar /
```

As `$` stands for end of line, `/$` matches those lines whose last character is a `/`.

Comment: Clear and simple solution.I'll mark it but i have to wait 8 minutes.

Comment: Damn! 8 upvotes in 16 mins. You're on a roll @fedorqui!! *Edit*: Sorry just read you reached your cap. Sniff Sniff

Answer (score 2):

```
grep '/$'
```

slash is **not special character** for grep and **$** means match expression at the **end of a line**.

---

You can even grep the last column with **only backlash** at **last column** (but not the only column in the line)

I assumed tha the **last column** of a line is a string with **more than one white space in front** the string and **no more character after** the string. This assumption **does not** fulfill the requirement if there has **only one column** in **that line** because it **does not need space** in front of it to show it is last column if there has only one column.

**By** enable **perl** regular expressions (-P),

```
grep -P '\s+/$'
```

\s   means matches any whitespace character (space, tab, newline)

plus sign means match 1 or more times for **preceding** element

$  means  end of string

**OR** refer to [Character Classes and Bracket Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html)

```
grep '[[:space:]]\+/$'
```

**OR**

```
grep '[[:blank:]]\+/$'
```

> ‘[:blank:]’ Blank characters: space and tab.
>
> ‘[:space:]’ Space characters: in the ‘C’ locale, this is tab, newline,
>   vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space. It is a synonym for '\s'.
>
> Refer to @fedorqui, the backslash after ]] is used to distinguish with
>   the literal +. Thanks for the explanations.

**Sorry** if wrong for perl answer because I **never** use or learn *Perl* expression but really hope can help you find the last column slash so may be you can read these for more information for searching backspace with slash at end of line

[grep with regexp: whitespace doesn't match unless I add an assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013152/grep-with-regexp-whitespace-doesnt-match-unless-i-add-an-assertion)

[Regular expressions in Perl](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html)

Comment: anyone can help me check if 2nd,3rd and 4th commands can get the last column with slash character or not? because I don't have any Linux machine nearby now and hunger to know the answer.thanks

Comment: Yes, all of them are working to me on `GNU bash, version 4.2.45`.

Comment: cool, I tried with the grep online tool but it gave negative result, by the way, thanks for your time to help me test.

Comment: Actually I have one thing not understand, about the Character Classes and Bracket Expressions answers.....why need to have backslash after ]] ? Is it possible to omit the backslash after ]]? I don't know its actual meaning in that expression.

Comment: Now I see that your attempts are checking if there is a slash *and* also if there is any number of spaces before. This is something the OP did not ask for. Regarding the `\` itself, it is to distinguish with the literal `+`. That is, if you don't add it, it will look for a `+/` ending.

Comment: because I understood "has a "/" character at their last column" as it has only '/' at the last column....so OP want "a/foo bar bb/" also his result?

Comment: if follow the requirement sentence for last column, all three lines of output are fulfilling the requirement...is it?

Comment: @fedorqui the + is for preceding element if not wrong,right?

Comment: It is OK, but in case you need to check for multiple spaces. Note that `[a]+` indicates "one or more values".