# django | class based views | user passwords not working using curl

Tags: django, curl, django-class-based-views

I am trying to learn to use django class based views .
I want to make a GET request and do some operations only if the user is super user , but when I call this API using curl , it always uses `AnonymousUser` irrespective of what I send via the CURL command.

**views.py**

```
class handle_request(View):

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(handle_request, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        print "GET request made"
        print request.user # <-- this is always AnonymousUser
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            return HttpResponse("User is not permitted this action",status=403)
        else: 
            # Do something
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', handle_request.as_view()),
    url(r'^db', hello.views.db, name='db'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

**curl command**

```
curl -u test:testpass http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

what is the correct way to pass username and password to class based django view ?

Comment: You would need to write some middleware that will authenticate the user for any request by passing the credentials, it is not automatic.

Comment: even if I don't write custom middleware, shouldn't username be available in the request body in views ?

Comment: If you log in. Have you?

Comment: It works if I call this api from browser after logging in admin site from browser first.

Comment: The -u flag is for HTTP Basic / Digest Auth (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) which is not the default Django auth. You can add it with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/ but you will need to configure your http server to manage authentication. Here is an answer using curl to authenticate with standard user/pass http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306515/how-to-curl-an-authenticated-django-app

Comment: @dotcomly - thanks . curl solution mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306515/how-to-curl-an-authenticated-django-app is working