# Running django admin command via curl or request.post

Tags: django, django-models, python-requests, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I have a special Django admin action called "run_test".

I would like to start that action from a Jenkins job on some items.

Something like this was my idea

```
import json
import requests


url = "http://localhost:8000/admin/app/model/"
item = { "user": "jenkins", 
         "password": "password", 
          "action": "run_test",
          "index": 0
       }
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept": "application/json"}

resp = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(item),headers=headers)

print(resp)
```

403 is the answer I got as a response.

Is there a way to run Django admin command with curl or request.post?

How can I include a queryset?

Note: manage.py command is not an option

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What is that post supposed to do? What "action" is meant to be triggered? What *exact* response do you get?

Comment: my action is called "run".
Ok I see this might be misleading.

I have some tests saved as a model instance. Jenkins schould run the post command to trigger some Tests inside django.

I modified my question a bit

Comment: But what is "run"? What kind of thing is it? Where is the code? How is it related to the URL /admin/app/model/?

Comment: as mentiond in my fisrt sentence: "django admin action called "run"".
Admin actions are normally "delete all selected items".
You can performthem by goind to localhost/app/admin -> and then click your model.
I created a new one which made some stuf with the selected items (index = 0)

For example my query would start the "run" command on Item with index  = 0, so the first item.

the run command itself is something like take that instance and add some values or delete some values. Nothing special.

To be precise: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Answer (score 0):

This requires a bit of stateful shell scripting -- login to admin area, obtain a magic cookie and then shoot your custom requests with the magic cookie included. Details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376188/148926).