# Why are cookies visible in Django app browser dev tools but not via curl?

Tags: django, curl, cookies, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use curl via bash script to store cookies using `curl -c cookies.txt https://www.mydjangoapp.com/` so that I can use the CSRF token in subsequent curl requests (using the `-b cookies.txt` option in subsequent commands).

However, when I run `cat cookies.txt` to view the contents, the file only contains the following:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.
```

Additionally, the cookies aren't viewable in the response when using the verbose `-v` option either.

When I check the cookies returned via Chrome Developer Tools, I see all the cookies that I expect.

I have verified that `cookies.txt` is populated with cookies when running the curl command against other endpoints.

Any ideas about how this might happen? In particular, I'm trying to get the CSRF token, but this seems to be a more general cookie retrieval issue with curl and my Django application.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because in the browser, I have already been navigating around as an authenticated user.

When I used curl to visit the login endpoint, `cookies.txt` was finally populated with the cookies I needed.

This [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306515/how-to-curl-an-authenticated-django-app/43584660#43584660) was essential to figuring this out.