# Problem with character class using grep on Windows

Tags: windows, grep

I'm trying to use grep on Windows to search all files in the current directory for the word `foo` followed by any white space.

I tried:

```
grep foo\s *
```

But it doesn't work.  It matches `foos` though.  I was under the impression that `\s` should match a white space.  Indeed it does in other regular expression testers.

I also tried `grep foo\\s *`  `grep "foo\s" *` and countless other attempts.

What am I missing?

I'm using GNU grep 2.5.4 on Windows 10 in cmd.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a bug with the handling of \s in grep up to version  2.5  [grep regex whitespace behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233159/grep-regex-whitespace-behavior)

You have several alternatives to it

```
grep "foo[ \t] *
grep "foo[[:space:]]" *
```

or if you dont care about tabulation

```
grep "foo " *
```

Comment: Is there a version of grep later than 2.5.4 with a fix?  Web search unfortunately directs me to [2.5.4](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) which I already have.

Comment: On my computer (ubuntu 18), this is grep 3.1. Probably you can find this version for win.